# Is there a way to attach a saved video from my pc in my HTML image map as opposed to a video link on a website? (code below)

Tags: html, video, imagemap

I have an image map with tons of different boxes on them and I want them to open short videos when you press each one. I understand how to add a website link for a video but I was wondering how I can make it so I can just download all of the videos and attach them that way. Here's an example of what I have. I normally type the website link after href.

.img src="example.jpeg" usemap="#image-map">

.map name="image-map">
.area target="_blank" alt="Huge Sweep" title="Huge Sweep" href="" coords="111,346,172,315" shape="rect">

I guess this leads to a 2nd question I have. Will others be able to still see the videos once I share the file? Or will it not work since the videos would be pointing to my directory. Is a website the only way it would work?

Comment: Use a data url.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url . Yes.  And in general, this is likely an awful idea.  I guess you're trying to hack around some limitation on the server you're using, yes?  What is it?  Why not switch to a better server to serve the content?

Comment: Either put files online or send file as **zip** (with HTML file and a subfolder of video files)